# Optimal gpu_mem_512 split for headless server

Tags: memory-split

I own a Raspberry PI model B with 512MB of RAM. I am not running any graphical application on it. It just run a few services and when I need to administer it I do that via SSH.

I see that my `/boot/config.txt` file contains the following line

```
gpu_mem_512=316
```

but since I am not using anything graphical at all it feels a bit of a waste. At the moment my system is not memory hungry, but I don't foresee I'm going to attach a screen to it so I'd like to have a memory split optimised for my use.

What is the optimal split for my situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the least you may allocate for GPU is 16MB, it works for me and should work for you just fine. put the following to `/boot/config.txt` and see:

```
gpu_mem=16
```

Comment: Just a note to complete your answer: `gpu_mem` sets the gpu memory for either 256M or 512M Pi's. `gpu_mem_256` and `gpu_mem_512` override this if running respectively on a 256M or on a 512M Pi.

Comment: I'm using this for headless server too and it's perfectly fine.